# Can't use "require" to load a module

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I am not able to successfully use "require" to load a module. My book dose not provide enough context.

it claims that this is all I should need in the module file(file is named "newjavascript.js":

```
var days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday"];

exports.name = function(number) {

return days[number];

};

exports.number = function(name) {

return days.indexOf(name);

};
```

And this is the require function I have as a separate file in netbeans:

```
function require(InterFaceFile) {

var code = new Function("exports", readFile(InterFaceFile));

var exports = {};

code(exports);

return exports;

}

console.log(weekDay.name(1));

output: "weekDay.name is not a function"
```

this is the same module it describes earlier in the book, it mentions this is more for the browser side:

```
(function(exports) {

 var days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday"];

 exports.name = function(number) {

 return days[number];

 };

 exports.day = function(name) {

 return days.indexOf(name);

 };

})(this.weekday = {});

console.log(weekday.name(1));
```

I understand that "weekDay" is no where in the first file, so I tried using the filename in its place(newjavascript.js, with and without quotations), and also tried wrapping the whole first chunk of code in a function named "weekDay", I tried on browser and in netbeans with no luck. I feel like if I can clear this up it will be smooth sailing from here on! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite `require`? It's already written for you--is this an exercise for reinventing the wheel? If so, it'd be nice to hear which book you're following. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like your question (or your code) is missing some lines, I would imagine this would work:

```
// code for require here
const weekDay = require("/path/to/weekday.js"):
console.log(weekDay.name(1)):
```

This seems like an exercise to understand how NodeJS style require works. 
Or if you're using the other method (module pattern):

```
const weekDay = (function(exports) {
 var days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday"];
 exports.name = function(number) {
 return days[number];
 };

 exports.day = function(name) {
 return days.indexOf(name);
 };

})({});

console.log(weekDay.name(1));
```

The step that's missing is actually "requiring" the module and binding the result to a variable you can use to call the functions on!

Comment: So I added "var weekDay = require("newjavascript.js")" and now it is saying "readFile is not defined", getting closer!

Comment: Okay, if this is NodeJS do this at the start of your file: const fs = require('fs'), then you can call fs.readFileAsync. (this require does the same thing as your own require but is the built in version)

Comment: it is saying "Cannot read property 'readFileAsync' of undefined".

Comment: I don't know if my netbeans has the information to load the fs module

Comment: I suppose your are not using NodeJS for this then. In that case you'll have to use the module pattern (the second example) to test this chapter.

Comment: Perhaps the next chapter asks you to install NodeJS if it's not focused on browser Javascript

Comment: The second example you mentioned returns "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" in browser and netbeans for me. Also I am using a node.js project within netbeans. node.js itself isn't covered in my book for a long time.

Comment: At the end of the code for the second example I missed adding "return exports"

Comment: If you're using NodeJS importing fs should work, try renaming your require function to something else to make sure it isn't colliding with the built in one

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the **browser code**:

```js
(function(exports) {

var days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday"];

exports.name = function(number) {
    return days[number];
};

exports.day = function(name) {
    return days.indexOf(name);
};

})(window.weekday = {});

console.log(weekday.name(1));
```

This runs in a browser and logs "tuesday" on the console. `this.weekday` was replaced by `window.weekday` for clarity - writing `this.weekday={}` to use `weekday` as a global variable name is confusing.

What the code does is *hard code* the body of an anonymous function whose parameter name is `exports,` and calls it with a newly created `window.weekday` object. After the call `weekday`, the value of the `exports` parameter, has been updated with new methods.

*The anonymous function code is presented to model how `require` works.*

---

**Server code**

Now consider generalizing the anonymous function model by creating a `require` function that

- creates and returns a new `exports` object for you,
- takes the **file path** of a file containing body code to modify `exports`,
- executes the body code inside a function which takes `exports` as an actual argument, under the formal parameter name of "exports".

You could then call it as

```
var weekday = require( filePath_of_script);
```

Using file paths for script files requires access to the file system. Since unrestricted access is not available  in browsers, this example dummies the `readFile` method mentioned in the book:

```js
function readFile( filePath) { // dummied example
  let fileContent =
 ` 
 var days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday"];
 exports.name = function(number) {
  return days[number];
 };

 exports.number = function(name) {
  return days.indexOf(name);
 };
 `;
 return fileContent;
}

function require(InterFaceFile) { // from netbeans
    // create a new function with first parameter named "exports":
    var code = new Function("exports", readFile(InterFaceFile));
    var exports = {};
    code(exports);
    return exports;
}

// usage example

var weekdays = require("newjavascript.js"); // create and save exports
console.log( weekdays.name( 1));
```

Note

- The book (or netbeans) presents a simple implementation of `require` - node's `require` method has additional features such as calling the body code with the `exports` object as its `this` value.
- The two lines shown after the `require` function declaration in the post

  ```
  console.log(weekDay.name(1));
  output: "weekDay.name is not a function"
  ```

  are out of place and should be removed.
- In these examples `weekDay` is a variable name used to save the exports object returned by `require`, or in the case of the anonymous function, a window property name used as a variable.